# New to Ruby and SQLite , don't know why my queries aren't working

Tags: ruby, sqlite

So I have one Ruby program that works fine that creates all of my tables, and another that is a basic user interface to modify the database.  I'm guessing that I can't just SELECT things and have it be assigned to variables?  I'm not sure exactly what us wrong with this.  This code never executes the menu, it stops after asking for the password.  Any advice would be great, most of the things I find on Ruby database stuff online deals with Rails.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'sqlite3'

begin

db = SQLite3::Database.open "database.db"
puts "Enter Employee ID:"
empID = gets.chomp
puts "Enter Password:"
passInput = gets.chomp

empPass = db.execute "SELECT password FROM employees WHERE employeeID = #{empID}"


if empPass == passInput
   menu
end

def menu
    i = 0
    loop do
        puts "1. Find a dvd.","2. Display all current inventory.","3. Enter a sale.","4. Add a DVD to inventory.",
        "5. Update inventory.","6. Quit."

        input = gets.chomp

        case input
        when "1"
            puts "Enter sku"
            skuInput = gets.chomp
            db.execute "SELECT * FROM dvds WHERE sku = #{skuInput}"

        when "2"
            db.execute "SELECT * FROM dvds WHERE numInInventory > 0"
        when "3"
            puts "Enter/Scan DVD Sku."
            saleSku = gets.chomp
            db.execute "UPDATE dvds SET numInInventory = numInInventory - 1 WHERE sku = #{salesSku}"
        when "4"
            puts "Enter Sku."
            skuInsert = gets.chomp
            puts "Enter DVD title."
            titleInsert = gets.chomp
            puts "Enter release year."
            yearInsert = gets.chomp
            puts "Enter length of film in minutes."
            lengthInsert = gets.chomp
            puts "Enter price."
            priceInsert=gets.chomp

            isThereInventory = db.execute "SELECT sku FROM dvds WHERE sku = #{skuInsert}"
            db.execute "INSERT INTO dvds VALUES(#{skuInsert}, #{titleInsert}, #{yearInsert}, 1, #{timeInsert}, #{priceInsert})"
        when "5"
            puts "Enter sku of the DVD you wish to update."
            updateSku = gets.chomp
            puts "Enter the number of copies you are adding to inventory."
            updateQuantity = gets.chomp
            db.execute "UPDATE dvds SET numInInventory = numInInventory + #{updateQuantity} WHERE sku = #{updateSku}"
        when "6"
            puts "Goodbye!"
            i = 1
        else
            puts "Invalid option: #{input}"
        end

        break if i == 1
    end
end


rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 

    puts "Exception occured"
    puts e

ensure
    db.close if db
end
```

Comment: Does *anything* after the `passInput = gets.chomp` link get run? If you just put a simple, `puts 'Hello, world!'` line after the capture of the password and ignore the db question entirely, does it work? In other words, are you sure it's the DB and not the line that captures the password somehow?

Comment: Or, any chance you need a semi-colon at the end of your select statement?

Comment: Yes, if I put Hello World after passInput = gets.chomp, then it does work.  I'm guessing that it isn't correctly checking the database for the password so the if statement isn't activating?

Comment: If you add `puts empPass` after the query, what do you get?

Comment: @UriAgassi program.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `empPass' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: o...k... how about `puts db.execute("SELECT password FROM employees WHERE employeeID = #{empID}")`?

Comment: @UriAgassi if I do that then it prints out the password from the database successfully, but then the program ends per usual.

Comment: One more test - `p db.execute("SELECT password FROM employees WHERE employeeID = #{empID}")`

Comment: @UriAgassi When I do that, it prints out [["password1"]], which is the password from the database, then program stops.  תודה על העזרה אחי

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.execute` returns an array of arrays. If you change your code to:

```
if empPass.flatten.first == passInput
   menu
end
```

Also, you probably need to define `def menu` *before* calling it.

it should work.

Comment: I did that and the program still ends after inputting the password.

Comment: Now I get program.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `menu' for main:Object (NameError)
Coreys-MacBook-Pro

Comment: Oh wow, that's new to me.  I'm used to Java where your methods can be anywhere.  Ok, so that got me to the menu successfully! Appreciate all the help achi. Now when I try to find a dvd in option 1, i'm getting this after entering the sku:  program.rb:19:in `block in menu': undefined local variable or method `db' for main:Object (NameError)
 from program.rb:9:in `loop'
 from program.rb:9:in `menu'
 from program.rb:67:in `<main>'

Comment: Try replacing `db` with `@db` everywhere

Comment: Do I need to connect to the database a second time during the loop?  Seems like it isn't recognizing the db anymore.

Comment: What does the @ do?  When I add those I get:  program.rb:19:in `block in menu': undefined method `execute' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from program.rb:9:in `loop'
 from program.rb:9:in `menu'
 from program.rb:67:in `<main>'

Comment: Did you add the `@` outside the method too? (in the `open`)? The `@` makes it an instance variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: Aha!  That worked!  Then the queries weren't printing out so I am adding puts in front of them now, and I'll let you know if I have any other problems.  Thanks again for all the help brother, and have a good Yom Ha'atzmaut!